# Not showing the unselected elements for map production

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I have made a selection using attributes, from two different feature classes, once I have done that, i want to make map, but i want other 'unselected elements' to be not seen in actual map, below picture for illustration.

[image]

Comment: Judging from the previous questions you asked, I'm assuming you are using ArcGIS? Please edit your question/tags to include the software and version you are using please.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to also include a picture to illustrate what you are trying to describe in a few words, please?

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to enter the criteria of your selections as SQL statements into the [Definition Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000) tab of the properties for each layer.

If the selections are complex, it may be simpler to make your selections, then right-click the layer and choose [Selection > Create Layer from Selected Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000p000000) which will create a whole new layer of just those features (note it's only a layer, *not* a new dataset - no 'export').

A third option would be to make use of the [Make Feature Layer GP](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool to do the same as the second option.

Comment: Dear Chris, Defin Query solves my problem. Thank you. Up Vote!

Comment: @MikeKevinire Happy to help. Please consider [accepting](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer by clicking the check mark to help let others know the issue has been solved..